# JS - Получение серверного времени и форматирование

Tags: javascript

Прошу помощи! В html будет передаваться серверное время на PHP. Необходимо взят ь время из тега span и увеличивать его на секунду. Необходимо в таком же формате его вывести.

**HTML:**

```
<span id="serverTime">08:19:01</span>
```

**JS:**

```
let time = document.getElementById("serverTime");

if (time != null) {
    setInterval(serverTime, 1000); //запускаем таймер на повтор функции
}

function serverTime() {

}
```

Comment: Где вашм попытки решить данную проблему?

Comment: попытки были.. иначе бы не было смысла мне писать сюда.

Comment: Собственно проблема у меня с форматированием времени (08:19:01). Не понимаю как можно преобразовать это в js объект класса Date.

Comment: Надо показывать ваши попытки, иначе выглядит как задание *"сделайте за меня"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const startTime = "08:12:50";
const [hours, minutes, seconds] = startTime.split(':').map((num) => parseInt(num));
const timeFormatOptions = {
  hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric'
}
const timeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru', timeFormatOptions);

let currTime = new Date();

currTime.setHours(hours, minutes, seconds);
setInterval(() => {
 currTime.setSeconds(currTime.getSeconds() + 1);
 console.log(timeFormat.format(currTime));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Это работает! Спасибо большое ))))

Comment: Этот код будет работать, но есть несколько нюансов, на которые стоит обратить внимание. 1) setInterval не гарантирует, что функция будет выполенена через 1 секунду, она пападет в стек, но если тот будет занят, то может произойти задержка с обновлением. 2) Если ваша вкладка станет неактивной, setInterval может прекратить свою работу в фоне, что приведет к сбитому времени, когда вы переключитесь обратно.

Comment: Можно запомнить разницу во времени, чтобы в функции выводить текущее время + разницу во времени, это решит проблему.